# Script para desconsiderar campos nulos sql server

Tags: sql

Olá, tenho uma tabela q possui inúmeras colunas (+ de 80), preciso de um script para desconsiderar os campos nulos e trazer somente os que possuem conteúdo.

Não quero usa is not null, pois teria que lista cada coluna e são muitas....Alguém pode me ajudar??

Comment: Você quer que ele traga uma tupla de tamanho variável para cada linha?

Comment: Queria q o select trouxesse apenas as colunas com conteúdo (valor)

Comment: Não é possível, as tuplas precisam ser homogêneos

Comment: Não teria nenhuma outra forma??

Comment: Não com tuplas, não na álgebra relacional. Talvez na aplicação que consome a consulta, mas não enxergo ganho com isso

Comment: Preciso para um relatório que me foi solicitado....

Comment: Como é o programa cliente que vai gerar o relatório?

Comment: Não vejo uma solução pro teu caso. Usando o NOT NULL teria que colocar para cada coluna e mesmo assim, muitas linhas não irizam exibir. Tem certeza que isso que eles estão requisitando?

Comment: Primeiro, nunca use `SELECT *`, sendo assim é só você escolher as colunas que deseja na consulta... Você está tentando resolver um problema X de causa Y...